# Date display in different locales in Java?

Tags: java

In java how do I display dates in different locales (for e.g. Russian).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use SimpleDateFormat constructor which takes locale. You need to first check if JDK supports the locale you are looking for, if not then you need to implement that.

Answer (score 14):

Something like:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ru","RU");
DateFormat full = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG, locale);
out.println(full.format(new Date()));
```

Should do the trick. However, there was a problem of [Russian Date formatting in jdk1.5](http://www.freshblurbs.com/incorrect-date-formatting-sun-jdk-1-5-russian-locale-implementation)

> The deal with Russian language is that month names have different suffix when they are presented stand-alone (i.e. in a list or something) and yet another one when they are part of a formatted date. So, even though March is "Март" in Russian, correctly formatted today's date would be: "7 Март**а** 2007 г."
>
> Let's see how JDK formats today's date: 7 Март 2007 г. Clearly wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Use the java.text.DateFormat class, you can construct that's configured to a specific Locale.

```
DateFormat format = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, theLocaleYouWant);
String text = format.format(new Date());
System.out.println(text);
```

Answer (score 3):

The [DateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) class can help you. As explained in the Javadoc:

> To format a date for a different
>   Locale, specify it in the call to
>   getDateInstance().
>
> ```
> DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG, Locale.FRANCE);
> ```

So you just need to adapt this code by using the adequate Locale.

Answer (score 0):

Use a java.util.Calendar with an appropriate time zone and locale.